# Resultant weight vector has same values in SAS/IML

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, sas, perceptron

I'm trying to create a binary perceptron classifier using SAS to develop my skills with SAS. The data has been cleaned and split into training and test sets. Due to my inexperience, I expanded the label vector into a table of seven identical columns to correspond to the seven weights to make the calculations more straightforward, at least, given my limited experience this seemed to be a usable method. Anyway, I run the following:

```
PROC IML;
    W = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    USE Work.X_train;
    XVarNames = {"Pclass" "Sex" "Age" "FamSize" "EmbC" "EmbQ" "EmbS"};
    READ ALL VAR XVarNames INTO X_trn;
    USE Work.y_train;
    YVarNames = {"S1" "S2" "S3" "S4" "S5" "S6" "S7"};
    READ ALL VAR YVarNames INTO y_trn;
    DO i = 1 to 668;
        IF W`*X_trn[i] > 0 THEN Z = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1};
        ELSE Z = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    W = W+(y_trn[i]`-Z)#X_trn[i]`;
    END;
    PRINT W;
RUN;
```

and the result is a column vector with seven entries each having value -2.373. The particular value isn't important, but clearly, a weight vector that is comprised of identical values is not useful. The question then is, what error in the code am I making that is producing this result?

My intuition is that something with how I am trying to call each row of observations for X_trn and y_trn into the equation is resulting in this error. Otherwise, it might be due to the matrix arithmetic in the W = line, but the orientation of all of the vectors seems to be appropriate.